# i want to insert rows as section in tableview in swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I'm successfully appending data at array but `UITableView` not inserting and showing that data.

But the following error showing

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 4
>   into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the
>   update'

I have tried like this :

```
        super.viewDidLoad()

    array1=["A1","B1","C1","D1"]
    array2=["A2","B2","C2","D2"]
    array3=["A3","B3","C3","D3"]
    array4=["A4","B4","C4","D4"]
    dict1=[0:array1,1:array2,3:array3,4:array4,2:names]
    print( (dict1))
    print( (dict1[1]?.count)!)
    print(dict1.keys.count)

}
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

{
   return (((dict1)[section])!.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == tableExplore {

    cellMain = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellExp", for: indexPath) as! ExploreLocallyCell
    cellMain.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 194.0/255, green: 198.0/255, blue: 198.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
        cellMain.textLabel?.text=(dict1[indexPath.section])?[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cellMain

}
 public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int // Default is 1 if not implemented
{


return dict1.keys.count
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    return (names)[section]

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
  self.insert(section:indexPath.section, row: indexPath.row)

}
func insert(section:Int,row:Int)
{
   print(dict1[section]!)
    // Update Table Data
    tableView.beginUpdates()
 dict1[section]!.append("BAlu")
    print(dict1[section]!)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:dict1[section]!.count-1, section: section)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// No need of tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() while you need to do one or two modification in UITableView 
// While you are inserting row in table programatically then no need of tableView.reloadData() because its has no meaning to do it. You should either insert or reload. It will give you same result. Diff is reload will take more performs time then insert row. 

func insert(section:Int,row:Int)
{
    print(dict1[section]!)
    // Update Table Data
    dict1[section]!.append("BAlu")
    print(dict1[section]!)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:dict1[section]!.count-1, section: section)], with: .automatic)
}

//Or
func insert(section:Int,row:Int)
{
    print(dict1[section]!)
    // Update Table Data
    dict1[section]!.append("BAlu")
    print(dict1[section]!)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```